# How to do the following updation in php oops through ajax using pdo. Below code shows no errors in the console but it's not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, oop, pdo

Payload image:

[image: Payload image]

I am trying the php oops operations with ajax for the first time. So please help.
It seems like no action is being performed when the submit button is clicked. I feel like the ajax is not redirecting to classhandler.php .

*opinion_form.php*

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
        <form method="POST" id="Formid" name="formnm" >
                 <input type="hidden" id = "page" name="page"/>
            <div class="row m-b-2">
                  
               <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                          
                      <h4 class="demo-sub-title">Who is your favourite author?</h4>
    
    <input type="radio"  name="name"  id="name" value="Miguel de Cervantes" required="required"/>Miguel de Cervantes
    <input type="radio"  name="name"  id="name" value="Charles Dickens" required="required"/>Charles Dickens
    <input type="radio"  name="name"  id="name" value="J.R.R. Tolkien" required="required"/>J.R.R. Tolkien     
    <input type="radio"  name="name"  id="name" value="Antoine de Saint-Exuper" required="required"/>Antoine de Saint-Exuper
                    </div>  
                      
              </div>  
    
          <center>  <!-- <button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"></button>-->
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
          </center>
                  
          </div>
             <button onclick="window.location='s.php' ">View Poll Results</button>
      </form>
    
    </body>
    
    
    <script src="templateadmin/assets/scripts/lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submit').click(function(){
  
var authorname = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]:checked').value;
 var submit = document.getElementById("submit").value;

   $.ajax({
    url : "classhandler.php",    
    method:"POST",     
    data:{name:authorname,submit:submit}, 
    success:function(data){
      result=data;
      //alert("Data Saved"); 
     //alert(data);   
     
     
    }
   });
return false;
  }); 
    </script>
    </html>
```

*opinions.php*

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';

class opinions
{
  private $db;
 
  function __construct($DB_con)
  {
    $this->db = $DB_con;
  }
 
 public function create($name)
 {
  
    try
    {
     
      //$name = $_POST['name'];
      $sql=$this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM opinions WHERE opinions_author_name= :fname");
      $sql->execute(array(
        ':fname' => $name
      ));
      $records = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $vote=$records['opinions_vote'];
       $vote=$vote+1; 
      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE opinions SET opinions_vote=:vote_count WHERE opinions_author_name=:author_name");
      
      $stmt->execute(array(
        ':author_name' => $name,
        ':vote_count' => $vote));
      return true;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      echo $e->getMessage(); 
      return false;
    } 
 }
}
```

*config.php*

```
<?php

$DB_host = "localhost";
$DB_user = "root";
$DB_pass = "";
$DB_name = "axelerant_db";


try
{
    $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
    $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

include_once 'opinions.php';

$crud = new opinions($DB_con);

?>
```

**classhandler.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

if(isset( $_POST['submit'] )) {
     $name=$_POST['name'];
     $result = $crud->create($name);
     //echo $result;
     // header("Location: opinions.php");
}
```

**table**

| opinions_id | opinions_author_name | opinions_vote |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Miguel de Cervantes | 0 |
| 2 | Charles Dickens | 0 |
| 3 | J.R.R. Tolkien | 0 |
| 4 | Antoine de Saint-Exuper | 0 |

**Network response for classhandler.php**

```
General
    
    Request URL: http://projects/php%20OOPS/classhandler.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers

Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 07 May 2021 13:30:58 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) PHP/7.3.12
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.12

Request Headers

Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 33
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host: projects
Origin: http://projects
Referer: http://projects/php%20OOPS/opinion_form.php
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Mobile Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Form Data

name: J.R.R. Tolkien
submit: submit
```

Comment: The simplest check is to see if the request is present in the Network tab. If not, then it's not being triggered.

Comment: Please present [MCVE]. We don't need to see all the code, just the part that doesnt' work. In your case, you need to show us that the AJAX call works. Open the network tab, trigger AJAX request and then tell us what was send as form data.

Comment: @Dharman, I have updated the network response in the question.Please have a look

Comment: Add `return false` to the end of your handler for `$('#submit').click(function(){` and then repeat and show us the actual AJAX response. What you are doing is submitting the form the normal way and then showing us the normal POST request. You need to prevent that and show us the AJAX request

Comment: @Dharman, I didn't understand what u have meant to do  with asking to prevent normal post request & to show ajax request. How to show only the ajax request?Please tell me.

Comment: @Dharman, I have added 'return false' & updated the question with network response from it. Have a check on it pls.

Comment: It should be working now. It works for me at least. Are you still facing some problems?

Comment: @Dharman, Mine is not working still. Submit button becomes short in length now, when it is clicked. Seems like no other action is being performed.

Comment: @Dharman,The above commented scenario occurs after the 'return false' has been added. Without adding it , seems like no single action is being performed.

Comment: @Dharman, Tell Me how it worked for u. What U have tried in ur browser about this?

Comment: The button text disappears because you make it so `$('#submit').val('');`. I didn't do anything, I just copied your code and added `return false`. Please tell us what happens on your side. Do you see status 200? Do you see ajax response that you expect? Try some more debugging steps. This code should work

Comment: @Dharman I have updated the question with the responses from both opinions.php & classhandler.php. Also, i have added header("Location: opinions.php"); in classhandler.php. Please have a look

Comment: I don't know what you are doing anymore. Why have you added `header("Location: opinions.php")`?

Comment: @Dharman, The network response was not showing that file name listed if not added.it shoulg go opinions.php & execute query, right? so, i tried it ,seen the same in many websites too. What else shall i try here?

Comment: Why do you want opinions.php? This makes no sense. You are including this file in config.php which in turn is included in classhandler.php. Why are you trying to redirect to the other file?

Comment: @Dharman, Removed  header("Location: opinions.php") & update dresponse .Check now.Do i need to make any changes for the redirecting to work properly?

Comment: What am I looking for? The code works. You get the status code 200. In fact your experiment with redirect proved that even the `if` statement is executed properly

Comment: @what more changes shall i need to make here.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Is the code still not behaving like you want it to?